# If two RDAP server responses disagree, what happens?

Tags: domain-registrar, whois

My current registrar (which I won't name here) seems to be having troubles. Their RDAP server is reporting very, very out-of-date information. And as I dig around it seems most (possibly all) of their customers' domains are showing up as expired (in some cases by more than a year). When I query [lookup.icann.org](https://lookup.icann.org/lookup), I see two "authoritative servers" listed, my registrar's and VeriSign's. The VeriSign data is current and correct. My registrar's data is not.

And while their WHOIS responses are not so blatantly incorrect, last week I renewed one of my domains and six days later the update is still not showing up on their WHOIS server or any other that I try. (This domain doesn't expire until the end of this month.)

So, what happens when conflicting information RDAP / WHOIS data appears? And at what point is there a risk that a domain that is in good standing at one registrar can be claimed by a user via another registrar?

I contacted my registrar about the RDAP issue last month, and five days ago they said it was fixed and that the changes would show up "shortly" but so far: nothing. RDAP seems like a core concern for a registrar, so I'm confused why this would happen. But I know almost nothing about domain registration (except as a customer), so I haven't a clue how I should be reacting to this and that moving to another registrar might be a huge over-reaction.